# How to get the CaseID when creating a CaseComment

Tags: visualforce, case, case-object, publisher, console

I have a VF page that will act as a Publisher Action on the Case Layout and will allow for the creation of a Case Comment. How can I pass in the CaseID since it is a required field on Case Comment? Here is the VF page so far.

```
<apex:page standardController="CaseComment" extensions="CaseCommentsExtension">
<apex:form>
  <apex:pageBlock title="Incident Comments" mode="edit">

  <apex:pageBlockButtons>

       <apex:commandButton action="{!Save}" value="Save"/>                  

   </apex:pageBlockButtons>


   <apex:pageBlockSection title="Comments" columns="1">
       <apex:inputField id="externalComment" value="{!CaseComment.CommentBody}"/>
  </apex:pageBlockSection>



  </apex:pageBlock>      
</apex:form>
```

Comment: Did you manage to achieve what you wanted to with this?

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for the "ParentId" field on the CaseComment object.

In visualforce you can fetch it using {!CaseComment.ParentId} or you can fetch it in Apex from the StandardController in your extension constructor similar to below:

```
public CaseComment record {get; private set;}

public CaseCommentsExtension(ApexPages.StandardController ctrl){
    record = (CaseComment)ctrl.getRecord();
    //Id parentCaseId = record.ParentId;
}
```

If you have questions on other fields, Salesforce has some excellent documentation.  A simple google for CaseComment fields in Salesforce revealed the following page:

http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_casecomment.htm

Answer (score 1):

To create a Visualforce page that you can use as a Publisher Action on the Case layout you need to use the Case standard controller, rather than the CaseComment standard controller. You can then use this in your extension to create a CaseComment with the correct parent.

**Visualforce**

```
<apex:page standardController="Case" extensions="CaseCommentsExtension">
    <apex:form>
        <apex:pageBlock title="Incident Comments" mode="edit">
            <apex:pageBlockButtons>
                <apex:commandButton action="{!saveComment}" value="Save"/>                  
            </apex:pageBlockButtons>
            <apex:pageBlockSection title="Comments" columns="1">
                <apex:inputField id="externalComment" value="{!comment.CommentBody}"/>
            </apex:pageBlockSection>
        </apex:pageBlock>      
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

**Controller Extension**

```
public class CaseCommentsExtension
{
    public CaseComment comment { get; set; }

    public CaseCommentsExtension(ApexPages.StandardController stdController) 
    {
        this.comment = new CaseComment(ParentId = stdController.getId());
    }

    public PageReference saveComment()
    {
        insert comment;
        return null;
    }
}
```